# MySQL SyntaxErrorException about UPDATE query

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I am trying to update a field in my table using Netbeans. The update statement is as follows:

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_reg"; 
try { 
Class.forName(driver); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","abc"); 
PreparedStatement state = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE supplier SET sname='" + txtname.getText()+"' , add='"+txtadd.getText()+"' WHERE sid ='" +txtid.getText() + "'"); 
state.executeUpdate(); 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Record sucessfully Updated"); 
}catch (Exception ex) { 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQL SyntaxErrorException`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'add=kegalle'where sid=001" at line 1

How can I solve it?

Comment: When you are using PerparedStatement why not do ...set(..) calls instead of plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `add` with backticks

```
UPDATE supplier 
SET sname='" + txtname.getText()+"', `add` = ...
                 here ---------------^---^
```

BTW you are not using prepared statement correctly.

Comment: @user2507358: First you need to escape `add`. Then you should have a look into *prepared statements*. [Here is a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for using it with Java and JDBC.

Comment: please wait. I made this cord using JDBC connection. So I'm posting it fully it as another question. Please answer that post. I'll put link at once it is posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149074/mysql-syntax-error-exception-on-update-query

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the way you're using `PreparedStatement`. Try this:

```
PreparedStatement state = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE supplier SET sname = ?, add = ? WHERE sid = ?");
state.setString(1,txtname.getText()); // sname (parameter 1)
state.setString(2,txtadd.getText()); // add (parameter 2)
state.setString(3,txtid.getText()); //sid (parameter 3) is actually a varchar?
state.executeUpdate();
```